# PHP Search from Database

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">

   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title>TEST QUERY</title>
   </head>

   <body>
     <form action="" method="GET">
Search:
<input type="text" name="query" />
<br /> Please Enter Last Name
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>

  <?php
  $db_hostname = 'localhost';
  $db_username = 'zvrub';
  $db_password = 'zvrub';
  $db_database = 'dbtest';

  $con = mysql_connect($db_hostname,$db_username,$db_password,$db_database);
  if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

 mysql_select_db($db_database, $con);
 $query = $_GET['query']; 
 $min_length = 1;
 if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ 
     $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 
     $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
     $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'HR DATA'
     WHERE (`LAST_NAME` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`LAST_NAME` LIKE  
     '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());                                      
      if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ 
      while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
      echo "<p><h3>".$results['title']."</h3>".$results['text']."</p>";

    }

    }
    else{ 
    }

}
else{ 
    echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
}
 ?>
 </body>

 </html>
```

I have this code but it gives me an error of: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''HR DATA' WHERE (`LAST_NAME` LIKE '%Bryant%') OR (`LAST_NAME` LIKE '' at line 1

Comment: Try replacing this 'HR DATA' with this \`HR DATA\`. use backticks instead of single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Try using backticks (`) instead of single quotes (') to delimit the table name

```
"SELECT * FROM `HR DATA`
```

Comment: Thanks you very much